# get auto increment value for an inserted row safely

Tags: php, mysql, synchronization

i have a table in the database contains `_id` column which is the primary key for this table , actually this column value is set by the auto increment approach , is there any safe way to get the value that the auto increment value given to the row i when i  make the insert  ??? i saw a solution says :" call `mysql_insert_id()` immediately after your insert query." is it safe to use( i.e does it get a wrong value if the same script in different thread )??? if not is there any way to make a synchronized block in php?

Comment: There's no multithreading in PHP, so what are you concerned about? As long as you sequence the query and `insert_id()` correctly within one connection, this should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as far as I know, the id returned from mysql_insert_id is the auto increment id from the last insert query for the current connection (mysql_connect) to the sql database. The only reason for having to call it right after the query is that if you run two insert queries right after each other, mysql_insert_id returns just the last query. It wouldn't be reliably possible to get the id from the first query. Also, it gets the id from the last query, so if you did an insert then update, then ran mysql_insert_id. It would return 0 because the last query (update) isn't an insert.

Also, php just calls the mysql function [mysql_insert_id](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/mysql-insert-id.html). From the mysql manual:

> The value of mysql_insert_id() is affected only by statements issued
>   within the current client connection. It is not affected by statements
>   issued by other clients.

Answer (score 0):

If your different threads are each using their own connection to the MySQL server, it should be fine. If not, you'll probably have to use a mutex or semaphore, which should be provided by your threading library.

Answer (score 0):

Yes; $id = mysql_insert_id(); straight after your query.

Comment: Please do not post comments as answers.

Comment: This isn't a comment, it is a valid answer to the OP's question: `is it safe to use...`

Answer (score 0):

It's usualy safe to do it, but there maybe be synchronization problems.

What i suggest is to put your sqls into a transaction block :

```
mysql_query('BEGIN TRANSACTION');

mysql_query('INSERT...');

$x = mysql_insert_id();

mysql_querry('COMMIT');
```

EDIT: you also may put a write lock on the table until you read the id and then release the lock. But you only need this if you have synchronization problems (same thread)

Answer (score 0):

In PDO, the correct way is to use [PDO::lastInsertId()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php)

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDBPDO";

try{
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
    VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";
    // use exec() because no results are returned
    $conn->exec($sql);
    $last_id = $conn->lastInsertId();
    echo "New record created successfully. Last inserted ID is: " . $last_id;
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}

$conn = null;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As well You can use single one query to get autoincrement id, like:

```
INSERT INTO table_name(field_1,field_2) VALUES(:field_1,:field_2) RETURNING id;
```

or

```
INSERT INTO table_name (field_1) OUTPUT INSERTED.id VALUES (?);
```

Both are returning your autoincrement id
Regarding to:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php